# Display Percentage below the total in the summary report

Tags: dashboard, joined-reports

I am trying to create a summary report in which I am trying to create percentage formula.I used the formula for calculating for percentage as

```
 Operational_Metrics__c.Primary_Segregated_Organic_Waste__c:SUM/Operational_Metrics__c.Total_Waste__c:SUM
```

But, I observed that it displayed percentage successfully as a separate column which is not my requirement.

[image]

My requirement is I want to display Percentage as below the total it should display 100% under sum of  waste total and 8.23% as percentage of primary organic waste under sum of primary organic waste total. could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a matrix report vs a summary report in order to be able to specify "At a specific row/column grouping level..."
An example can be found here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_analytics/Content/analytics3_step2.htm